# Return multiple value of array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

```
$array = [
  'H',
  'E',
  'L',
  'L',
  'O',
];
```

This is my array. I want to print this array like this :

```
H
HE
HEL
HELL
HELLO
```

I want to do this **dynamically** .
For example, write a function to receive the array and do this with the array. Any array is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested `for` loops to print the pattern as follows:

```
$array = [
     'H',
     'E',
     'L',
     'L',
     'O',
];
echo printPattern($array);

function printPattern($array){
     $ret = '';
     for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){
          $str = '';
          for($j = 0; $j < $i+1; $j++){
               $str .= $array[$j];
          }
          $ret .= $str.'<br>';
     }
     return $ret;
}
```

Comment: How can i use this in a function ?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the array to a string, then iterate over the length of the string (either count the array or use `strlen()`, they'll be the same) and use `substr()` to get the given length, which will be the same as the number of the iteration.

```php
$array = [
  'H',
  'E',
  'L',
  'L',
  'O',
];
$string = implode("", $array);
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($array); $i++) {
    echo substr($string, 0, $i)."\n";
}
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/ibXpK